# Java swing in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I learned Java using BlueJ and now am starting to work with Eclipse. I was trying to make a simple GUI but I am getting errors for trying to import javax.swing.JFrame or javax.swing.JPanel. I have no clue why this is happening. Do I need to install swing to eclipse or what do I do to be able to use it.

Heres the code btw:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public static void main (String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    }
}
```

I already get erros when I try and import javax.swing.JFrame; I am very lost with why theres errors, please help!

Comment: That's not valid Java -- you have no class declaration after the import statements. All the code after the imports need to be enclosed within a class structure, e.g., `public class MyClass {..... code goes here ....}`. You don't have this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier if you use the menu.  It may be slightly different in your setup so look for the icon.

[image]

`Click here       ^`

Near the bottom, you should also select `create a static main entry point`.
You may also need to fill in the Project information.

You can also go to create new Project from the file menu.